# Graphing Library for Java

Tags: java, graph

I am working on a program which gathers data and stores it in a file. I need to be able to write a program which reads from the created file and plots a scatter/bar/pie graph from it. Does anyone know any Graphing Libraries which I can use to do this? I've seen suggestions for libraries which can graph nodes, vertices etc. but none for common graphs. Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have a look into http://jgrapht.org/

Comment: You could easily do it simply using Graphics2d aka swing.

Comment: You could easily do it simply using Graphics2d aka swing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For charts you can use [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/). It is an open sorce java library with a good API.
If you want to draw graphs (trees for example) you can use [JGraphX](https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx) which is also an open source library.